# Weird jumping in Draggable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

For fun I have been trying to create my own dragable divs and I have run into an issue or two.

The first and most annoying one is trying to allow the user to drag from where ever in the div they happen to click. This works great on both top left and bottom right. However on bottom left and top right they flip flop, as in you click one and it jumps to the other. I cannot seem to come up with a solution for this.

```
 function DragMe(e) {
    var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
    var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e) {
       $('.move').offset({
           top: e.pageY - relativeXPosition,
           left: e.pageX - relativeYPosition,
        });
    });
};

$('.move').on('mousedown', DragMe);

$('.move').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).off('mousedown');
    $(document).off('mousemove');
    $('.move').on('mousedown', DragMe);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpM9j/

This is what I have so far, also if anyone knows how I might get started on making this work on multiple divs that would be awesome. I tried before but it just snapped all the divs together and so one would disappear.

I understand this is probably do-able with jQuery UI but I was hoping to avoid that for now just to make it a bit more challenging since I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite easy:
You mixed up X and Y inside the callback function

```
function DragMe(e) {
    var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
    var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e) {
       $('.move').offset({
           top: e.pageY - relativeYPosition, // you had relativeXPosition here
           left: e.pageX - relativeXPosition, // you had relativeYPosition here
        });
    });
};

$('.move').on('mousedown', DragMe);

$('.move').mouseup(function() { // drop the other offs and ons
    $(document).off('mousemove');
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VpM9j/2/

To answer your second question:

```
function DragMe(e) {
    var dragDiv = e.target;
    var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - dragDiv.offsetLeft);
    var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - dragDiv.offsetTop);

    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e) {
       $(dragDiv).offset({
           top: e.pageY - relativeYPosition,
           left: e.pageX - relativeXPosition,
        });
    });
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VpM9j/4/

But even better is event delegation, as you only need 1 event listener on the document and not  may for as many divs you have:

```
function DragMe(e) {
    var dragDiv = this; // <-- pay attention to that ;o)
    var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
    var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e) {
       $(dragDiv).offset({
           top: e.pageY - relativeYPosition,
           left: e.pageX - relativeXPosition,
        });
    });
};

$(document).on('mousedown', '.move', DragMe);

$(document).on('mouseup', '.move', function() {
    $(document).off('mousemove');
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VpM9j/7/

For further infos about event delegation see: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and there search for 'Direct and delegated events'

Comment: None of the variants found all over the internet worked so smoothly for my implementation except this.  Thanks to you and the OP.